# Angular - How to have two separate image uploads in one Form

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12 I want to have two separate image uploads in one form because they are going to difference places:

component:

```js
_id!: number;
licImageDirectoryPath: any = this.api.imageURL + 'licence/';
licenceInfoForm!: FormGroup;
files ? : any;
data: any;
url = '';

ngOnInit(): void {
  this._id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.loadEmployeeById();
  this.updateLicence();
}

onSelectFrontFile(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
    this.files = event.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event: any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
      //   console.log(event);
      this.url = event.target.result;
    }
  }
}

onSelectBackFile(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
    this.files = event.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event: any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
      this.url = event.target.result;
    }
  }
}

updateLicence() {
  this.licenceInfoForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    front_page: ['', [
      RxwebValidators.extension({
        extensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif", "svg"]
      })
    ]],
    back_page: ['', [
      RxwebValidators.extension({
        extensions: ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif", "svg"]
      })
    ]],
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body box-profile">
  <div class="text-center">
    <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" [src]="employee.front_page ? licImageDirectoryPath+employee.front_page : url || 'assets/img/no-image.png'" alt="No Front Page" onerror="this.src='assets/img/assets/img/no-image.png'" style="height:150px; width:150px">
  </div>
  <h6 class="profile-username text-center">Licent (Front Page)</h6>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input formControlName="front_page" id="front_page" type="file" class="form-control" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.bmp,.png,.gif,.svg" (change)="onSelectFrontFile($event)">
    <div *ngIf="fl.front_page.touched && fl.front_page.invalid">
      <div *ngIf="fl.front_page.hasError('extension')">
        <div class="text-danger">
          Enter valid File Type!
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
  <div class="card-body box-profile">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img class="profile-user-img img-fluid img-circle" [src]="employee.back_page ? licImageDirectoryPath+employee.back_page : url || 'assets/img/no-image.png'" alt="No Front Page" onerror="this.src='assets/img/assets/img/no-image.png'" style="height:150px; width:150px">
    </div>
    <h6 class="profile-username text-center">Licent (Back Page)</h6>
    <div class="form-group">

      <input formControlName="back_page" id="back_page" type="file" class="form-control" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.bmp,.png,.gif,.svg" (change)="onSelectBackFile($event)">
      <div *ngIf="fl.back_page.touched && fl.back_page.invalid">
        <div *ngIf="fl.back_page.hasError('extension')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Enter valid File Type!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am to preview the images before I submit. I am selecting front page and back page of licence separately and then submit to upload. But I found that when I select the front page image uploader, it loads the same image in both front page and back page. The same thing happen when I select image for back page too.

How do I eresolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to select two different files, but associating both to the same `files` and `url` properties.

You probably need something like:

```
readonly files: Record<string, any> = { frontImage: null, backImage: null };
readonly urls: Record<string, any> = { frontImage: null, backImage:null };
```

Then you could make the associations individually, e.g.

```
onSelectFrontFile(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
    this.files.frontImage = event.target.files[0]; // associates the file to the a different property
    reader.onload = (event: any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
      //   console.log(event);
      this.urls.frontImage = event.target.result;
    }
  }
}

onSelectBackFile(event: any) {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
    this.files.backImage = event.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = (event: any) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
      this.urls.backImage = event.target.result;
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, read them correctly at your component's HTML.